# Does random count twice in the achievements?

Tags: starcraft-2, achievements

Does the random choice of faction count twice in the achievements?

So if I get randomly assigned to the Zerg and win my match, would this count as a victory for both my random and Zerg achievements or just for random?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It does seem so.
I play random and got an achievement for 50 wins as random as well as the 10 wins as terran, zerg and protoss achievements.

Comment: I think that's server lag, and later you'll see those disapear

Comment: I will check if they still exist when i'm at home later today but i think i still saw them yesterday.

Comment: I checked to make sure. I currently have 22 wins as terran, 14 as zerg and the same for protoss. I never played anything else than Random, so it does definatly count twice.

Comment: I woudn't have expected it different, winning random as zerg not counting as winning while playing zerg would be strange.

Comment: Yes this works as it did in beta phase 2 as well.

Answer (score 4):

Yes it does count.  I play random all the time now and a win as random counts towards the random achievement and the race you were given.  This isn't lag or a bug.